# coredump when calling virtual method of a dynamic allocated object

Tags: c++, linux, gcc9

The snippet below will coredumped in `fun()` method. Why calling `c->b.f()` works in `main()` but failed in the function call?

```
class A {
 public:
  inline virtual void f() const {printf("A\n");}
};

class B : public A {
 public:
  inline void f() const override {printf("B\n");}
};

class C {
 public:
  B b;
};

void fun(const B &b) {
  b.f();                         // coredump
}

int main() {
  C *c = (C*)malloc(sizeof(C));
  c->b.f();                      // print "B"
  fun(c->b);
  return 0;
}
```

I guess it's because the virtual table is not initialized properly.

Comment: `*c` is uninitialized memory after the malloc. Objects need to be properly constructed.

Comment: Malloc here just allocating some memory, but not calling the constructor, you need to call constructors explicitly after memory initialization.
Put this line after memory allocation to call constructor of C.

```new (c) C();```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating memory for class C using malloc, but this **doesn't create any object of class C**. your program don't have any valid object and have **undefined behavior**.

As it is undefined behavior, your program may fail or may not be at `c->b.f();`

If you really want to use malloc, you should use **placement new** in your program to create object of your class.

```
C *c = (C*)malloc(sizeof(C));
new (c) C();
```

And to destroy your object and free the allocated memory, you should do

```
c->~C();
free(c);
```

Comment: memory allocated with `malloc` should always be freed by `free`

Comment: @sp2danny I read more about delete and free, I modified answer according to your suggestion.